# KeyListener does not work

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

What is wrong with this code?

`addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());`

```
private class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyPressed(e);
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            System.out.println("test");
            if(key==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE || key==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER || key==KeyEvent.VK_P) {
                paused = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This should print test in the console but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no need to call ``super.keyPressed(e)`` in a KeyAdapter subclass - the super method is documented to do nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The components you're listening on may not be focused. If you're going down the KeyListener route, see if you get a focus event and check if isFocusable is true for your element.

In any case, if you only want to bind a few keys you're better off using KeyBindings:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: It is focused and i know this because the mouse events are running

Comment: @usama8800: what do mouse events have to do with telling us what component has focus? Answer: they don't prove anything about the focus. You never tell us what you're adding the KeyListener to, and for all we know it could be the JFrame or a JPanel. Don't make any assumptions until your program works. 1+ to skishore's decent answer. I second the recommendation to use Key Bindings.

Comment: i used setFocuable(true) and it fixed it.

Comment: @usama8800: You've accepted the correct answer, but I fear that you're making the wrong fix. Again, the solution is to use Key Bindings. To see why this is important, please see [my answer on the same subject from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18156051/522444). Run the two programs that I've posted and see how they behave after the button is pressed, and you'll get a better understanding on the issues involved.