# Key Listener not working in JApplet

Tags: java, swing, applet, keyboard-events

This is a break the brick type of game where the user cannot let the ball fall below the paddle.  By the way paddle_x is sets the x coordinate of the paddle.  I have a MouseListener that works very well however, the KeyListener does not.  I am wondering what I am doing wrong and if anyone has any suggestions.

```
public PaintSurface() {
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() 
    {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getX() - 30 - paddle_x > 5)
                english  = 1.5f;
            else if(e.getX() - 30 - paddle_x < -5)
                english = - 1.5f;
            else
                english = 1.0f;
            paddle_x = e.getX() - 30;
        }
    });
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED){
                if(e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                    paddle_x += 30;
                }
                else if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                    paddle_x -= 30;
                }
            }
        }
    });


    ball = new Ball(20);

}
```

Comment: Please see [link to similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+keylistener+not+working+body%3Abindings). The best solution: use Key Bindings here, not a KeyListener. Otherwise you're going to have use a kludge to give focus to something that shouldn't have the focus. [Another example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18156051/522444).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Component which has a registered `KeyListener` must have `focus` for the `KeyListener` to fire. Call `requestFocus` on the Component to request that the component has focus, or use [KeyBindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) (recommended)

In addition, the `keyPressed` method has a conditional that checks the ID against `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED` events (which will never happen).

Comment: is there a way that i can check how long the key was pressed using key bindings

Comment: You might be able to use different actions for key pressed and key released - see the [3 parameter KeyStroke constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29) in the API.